# Installing libusb-1 and libudev to get openni to compile on Fedora

Tags: fedora, openni, libusb-1.0

I have just changed to Fedora 20 and I am trying to get used to it and to learn it. Before I have only worked with ubuntu so there are some new things for me.

I have tried to compile openni_master by downloading the package from git. The first step is to enter

```
   /OpenNi_Master/Platform/Linux/CreateDist/
```

ans to run
     sudo ./RedistMaker .

When I do that I get the following:

```
  fatal error: libusb-1.0/libusb.h: No such file or directory.
```

So I tried running

```
  sudo yum install libgusb.x86_64.
```

Running locate libgusb gives the .so files

```
  /usr/lib64/libgusb.so.2
  /usr/lib64/libgusb.so.2.0.3
```

but no libusb-1.0.h.

So I tried downloading the package libusb-1.0.18 from the web and compile it on my computer.
But running ./configure in the folder gives

```
  checking for libudev.h... no
  configure: error: "udev support requested but libudev not installed"
```

So I installed

```
  libgudev1-devel.x86_64
```

and

```
  libgudev1.x86_64.
```

Probably I am installing the wrong packages, but I am new to Fedora and I don't really know where to search for them.

Any help is appreciated!

/ Erik

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Fedora (and other distros using yum for package management), you can find out which package provides a certain file like so:

```
$ yum provides /path/to/my/file
```

If you only know a portion of the filename, you can use wildcards:

```
$ yum provides */myfile
```

So, what provides `libusb.h`?

```
$ yum provides */libusb.h
[...]
libusbx-devel-1.0.17-1.fc21.x86_64 : Development files for libusbx
Repo        : rawhide
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h
[...]
```

So you need to install `libusbx-devel`.

Comment: Thank you for your instruction, that was helpful! / Erik

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but libusb.h was present.

```
# CFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -march=native " ./configure --enable-scrypt --enable-Avalon
...
checking libudev.h usability... no
checking libudev.h presence... no
checking for libudev.h... no
configure: error: "udev support requested but libudev not installed"
configure: error: ./configure failed for compat/libusb-1.0
```

Fixed by installing an updated libudev:

```
# yum provides */libudev.h
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.clouvider.net
 * epel: ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de
 * extras: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * rpmforge: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * updates: mozart.ee.ic.ac.uk
libudev-devel-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64 : Development files for libudev
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/include/libudev.h

# yum install libudev-devel-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.clouvider.net
 * epel: ftp-stud.hs-esslingen.de
 * extras: centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk
 * rpmforge: fr2.rpmfind.net
 * updates: mozart.ee.ic.ac.uk
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libudev-devel.x86_64 0:147-2.73.el6_8.2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: udev = 147-2.73.el6_8.2 for package: libudev-devel-147-2.73.el6_8.2.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package udev.x86_64 0:147-2.46.el6 will be updated
---> Package udev.x86_64 0:147-2.73.el6_8.2 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

# CFLAGS="-O2 -Wall -march=native " ./configure --enable-scrypt --enable-Avalon
...
checking libudev.h usability... yes
checking libudev.h presence... yes
checking for libudev.h... yes
checking for udev_new in -ludev... yes
```